# How to solve a system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: nonlinear-system

How can one solve this system of equations:
$$
\begin{align}
x(t) = a \cos(\omega t + \phi) + \dfrac{\beta a^3}{32} \cos(3(\omega t + \phi)), \\
p(t) = -a \omega \sin(\omega t + \phi) - 3 \omega \dfrac{\beta a^3}{32} \sin(3(\omega t + \phi)),\\
\omega = \omega_0 + \dfrac{3}{8} a^2,
\end{align}, \\
\text{if } x(0) = x_0, p(0) = p_0
$$
where $\omega_0, \beta$ are constants?

I can write:

$$
\begin{align}
x_0 = a \cos(\phi) + \dfrac{\beta a^3}{32} \cos(3\phi), \\
p_0 = -a \omega \sin(\phi) - 3 \omega \dfrac{\beta a^3}{32} \sin(3\phi)),\\
\omega = \omega_0 + \dfrac{3}{8} a^2,
\end{align}
$$
But i can't figure out how to solve it for $a$ and $\phi$. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but possibly helpful. Make use of the triple angle formulas
\begin{align}
\sin(3\theta) &=3\sin\theta−4\sin^3\theta,\\
\cos(3\theta) &= 4 \cos^3\theta - 3 \cos \theta.
\end{align}
The first equation ($x_0 = \cdots$) will end up being third order in $\cos\phi$ and  the other ($p_0 = \cdots$) third order in $\sin\phi$. With a bit of luck you can solve the first for $\cos\phi$ and the second for $\sin\phi$, then take  it from there knowing that $\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi = 1$.

Comment: I made a few edits to my suggestion. Doesn't seem likely there's a closed-form solution.